# Replace ring encoder in a circuit

Tags: potentiometer, rotary-encoder

So a ring encoder on my car's HVAC control module went bad.
There is another identical encoder on the same PCB. I took readings of the voltage across al five pins of the working one while changing positions.
I'm not sure what all the pins are for. The encoder has some integrated LEDs, so one might be for that.

I would like to temporarily attach some other component that can replicate the behaviour, maybe some simple potentiometer? Any ideas?
I don't really mind if it breaks entirely, I am gonna have to replace the whole thing probably (sourcing the component proved impossible)

Found [this](https://www.mouser.mx/ProductDetail/Alps-Alpine/EC50A0920404?qs=hqbSiJllDNMYbnCpWaNs%252BQ%3D%3D) similar component, but it only has 3 pins as all of the others I have found.

Pin function:
pin1: ?
pin2: ground
pin3: Output
pin4: 5.0 VCC
pin5: ?

Here's a table of the voltages read on the 5 pins (except ground pin):

(empty cells I did not bother to measure but you can see the trend)

| Position | pin1 | pin3 | pin4 | pin5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6.33V | .89V | 5.0V | 8.0V |
| 1 | 6.30V | 1.28V | 5.0V | 7.97V |
| 2 | 6.25V | 1.67V | 5.0V | 7.95V |
| 3 | 6.22V | 2.09V | 5.0V | 7.93V |
| 4 | 6.19V | 2.45V | 5.0V | 7.90V |
| 5 | - | 2.9V | 5.0V | - |
| 6 | - | 3.3V | 5.0V | - |
| 7 | - | 3.68V | 5.0V | - |
| 8 | - | 4.06V | 5.0V | - |
| 9 | 6.09V | 4.44V | 5.0V | 7.81V |
| 10 | - | 4.85V | 5.0V | - |

[image: enter image escription here]
[image: enter image escription here]

Comment: what's printed on the encoder?

Comment: the LEDs are mounted on the board

Comment: Fourth pin of the one that "only has 3" might be the outer case.